# Paste JavaScript code into mobile browser from clipboard – Android

Tags: javascript, android, security, browser, clipboard

I want to put javascript code into android's browsers apps from clipboard. It works fine, but chrome always deletes word "javascript:" from pasted data.
For example: instead of `javascript:(function(){` it paste only `(function(){`.
How can I paste JS without auto-deleting?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible reason for your problem.**
Google doesn't support access to clipboard using Chrome anymore.

You can try this trick though:

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?rq=1)